# Login to Game Center But Return error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, game-center

I am trying to login with game center with iOS 8 but this error

```
   Error is Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=15 "The requested operation could not be completed because
     this application is not recognized by Game Center." UserInfo=0x17446c0c0

    {
    NSLocalizedDescription=The requested operation could not be completed because this application is not recognized by Game Centre.
    }
```

Comment: run through the game center programming / itunes connect guide. The message tells you that the app hasn't been set up with itunes connect as a game center enabled app. This is all explained here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectGameCenter_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: app work fine on iOS 7,6 but iOS 6 cannot login this error return.

Comment: If games or mobile phone is not original application shows up this error message also.

Comment: Also, there are two places on the iTunes Connect meta page for a project that must be set to enable Game Center for a project you're submitting for review.  There's the Game Center tab at the top of the page that contains the  lists of leaderboards/achievements you created in development. Then there's the Game Center switch at the bottom of the page, below the Build section, where, once you click it on, you get lists of leaderboards and achievements to be transferred to the production side of the Apple environment.

Comment: I'm getting this error suddenly on an app running on a iOS 9 device. The game center stuff ran fine for months, but now get this. Frustrating. I surely did not change any GC related issues.